# Displaying charts using F# Ionide plugin in Visual Studio Code or Atom

Tags: charts, visual-studio-code, atom-editor, f#-interactive, ionide

I am trying to visualise some data using F# script in Visual Studio Code or Atom (tried them both). There simple examples that show how it works using XPlot Google Charts:

https://tahahachana.github.io/XPlot/
http://tomasp.net/blog/2016/fslab-ionide/

But I don't get any chart output. If I execute a code like this:

```
inputs
|> Chart.Combo
|> Chart.WithOptions 
     (Options(title = "Coffee Production", series = 
        [| for typ in series -> Series(typ) |]))
|> Chart.WithLabels 
     ["Bolivia"; "Ecuador"; "Madagascar"]
|> Chart.WithLegend true
|> Chart.WithSize (600, 250)
```

I only get output in FSI window:

> val it : GoogleChart =   XPlot.GoogleCharts.GoogleChart {Height = 250;
>                                     Id = "85c0bc41-3ae2-4a40-8517-da33aa7ad713";
>                                     Width = 600;}

... which is of course correct, what else may be displayed in a text window? But how do I get the graphical output in VS Code or Atom using F# interactive? I am obviously missing something basic but what?

Comment: If you load it via `#load` then the registered fsi output handler should open the chart in a new browser window... (the blog only applies to Atom, because Ioined in VS Code does not support pretty HTML outputs...)

Comment: Thanks Tomas, now it does, both VS Code and Atom shows output in external browser window. But I thought I had seen screenshot where the output was shown by Atom. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This question came up on a search for Visual Studio Code Insiders and .NET Interactive.  It looks like this is the way to get XPlot inline for now:

```
#i "nuget:https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json"
#r "nuget:xplot.plotly.interactive"
```